# Xcode sprite kit how to select specific node

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite

I'm trying to create a moving floor in sprite kit. I used a for loop to fill the screen with 'tiles' and I'm moving them across the screen. If their xposition is less than 0 they will get removed. Now I want to add a tile behind the last tile. But I don't know how to get the xposition of the last tile (this will be the tile with the highest position value since it moves from right to left). Here is my code:

```
-(void)createTile:(float)xpos {
SKSpriteNode *tile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"tile"];
tile.name = @"tile";
float tilesize = (CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)/20);
tile.yScale = tilesize/24;
tile.xScale = tilesize/24;
tile.position = CGPointMake(xpos, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
[self addChild:tile];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime { 
//Going through all the tiles an moving them all

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"tile" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.x < 0.){
        [node removeFromParent];
        //[self createtile:(where the argument must be the position of the last floortile + the size of floortile]
    }
    node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x -3, node.position.y);

}];
}
```

EDIT: Forgot I had the floor array in there, I did not want the last object of the floor array but the last object of the childNodeTree. How do I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the last object in your floorArray always going to be the object with the highest x value? Assuming you created the floor tiles by iterating left to right on the screen? And then as you add more to the screen, you'll add them to the array, and then that tile will be the furthest to the right and the last in the array.

```
SKSpriteNode *lastTile = [floorArray lastObject];
```

EDIT for Comment:

```
NSArray *allChildNodes = myScene.children;
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the lastobject of the children nodes?

Comment: I think the floorArray sounds like the better option, just adding and subtracting, but every SKNode has a property called children which returns an array of all child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

since you know the x position of the removed tile and you should know how many tiles you have per row, you could simply calculate the position by offsetting the removed position by

```
numberOfTilesPerRow*tileWidth.
```

Even easier, assuming your tiles fill the whole screen when starting by x=0, and you have one tile extra to fill the gap while moving:

```
_______        _______
|OOOOO|O   -> O|OOOOOO|
|OOOOO|O      O|OOOOOO|
------         -------
```

the new position would be

```
parentWidth+tileWidth+removedNode.position.x
```

Comment: Tried this solution but it doesn't work for all the different speeds I tried out. Still, thanks for your input.